# How to remove white space from the top of my website page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

[How to remove white space from the top of this website](https://www.nspcollege.com/)

I had added

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

on my  css but still i am getting that white space

Comment: https://www.nspcollege.com/about 'site can't be reached'

Comment: " . " <-- if you know what I mean

Comment: Use the browser developer tools to find out which element is responsible for that space. If you don't know how to use the browser developer tools, this is a good time to stop what you're doing and learn its basics.

Comment: It's showing that part in html

Comment: @waqasMumtaz http://www.nspcollege.com/ here islink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer tools shows some characters at the beginning of your `body` tag. Remove them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have `.` (dot) right above in `body`, remove it